# How to specify translation for strings in twig template & php files

Tags: theming, 8, i18n-l10n

I've found a lot of examples and modules where such expressions are used .

In php files

```
 t('Submit this form'),
```

In twig files

```
 {{ 'Send'|trans }}
```

So as I know this is used for the translation purpose, and I've also used these functions in my theme & modules.

But the question is where I can specify translation for these words & phrases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do that with the User interface translation, "/admin/config/regional/translate" (which is part of the multilingual core package).
By the way you can also use:

```
{% trans %} Your english text {% endtrans %}
```

Comment: Thanks, as usual it very "easy" to find a configuration page